# Why does Perl sometimes recycle references?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

The following code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
print "array ref is ".\@array."\n";

my @copy_refs;
for my $element(@array) {
    my @copy = @array;
    print "copy ref is ".\@copy."\n";
    push @copy_refs, \@copy;
}
```

produces the following output, as one might expect:

```
array ref is ARRAY(0x21ae640)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21e2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d7368)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d71e8)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d70c8)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d6fa8)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d6e88)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d6d68)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21d6c48)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21cf8a0)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x21cf780)
```

However, the same code, with `push @copy_refs, \@copy;` removed, produces the following output:

```
array ref is ARRAY(0x229e640)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x22d2a00)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your code already does `push @copy_refs, \@copy;`. Do you mean "the same code, with `push @copy_refs, \@array`" ?

Comment: If you don't save the reference to `@copy` for each iteration, it will get destroyed on each loop iteration. Hence, the next array `@copy` may use the same memory address as the previous

Comment: Your comment makes a lot of sense Hakon. I think it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Perl uses reference counting to determine when to free variables. A variable is freed as soon as nothing references it. Code blocks (e.g., subs and files) maintain a reference to the lexical variables declared within them while the variables are in scope, so variables normally get deallocated on scope exit.

In other words, `my @copy` allocates a new array. When the scope is exited, `@copy` gets freed if nothing else references it.

When you do `push @copy_refs, \@copy;`, `@copy_refs` references the array, so `@copy` isn't freed.

When you omit `push @copy_refs, \@copy;`, nothing references `@copy`, so it's freed. This leaves the memory available to be reused in the next loop pass.

Kinda.

As an optimization, if nothing references a variable when it goes out of scope, it's merely cleared rather than destroyed and recreated. So `@copy` is not being merely reallocated at the same location; it's actually the very same array that's been cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, `my @copy = @array` creates new array with name `@copy` and copies each and every element from `@array`.

If you `push @copy_refs, \@copy` then array `@copy` is not destroyed at the end of the loop cycle step, on new cycle of the loop the `@copy` is continue to exist, new `@copy` array is created it occupies new location in memory (memory space address is changed).

If you do not `push @copy_refs, \@copy` then array `@copy` is destroyed at the end of loop cycle step and recreated on next cycle step of the loop in probably same memory location (you can see that it's address is the same from previous step of the loop).

Memory occupied by some variable only freed when the code stops to use it - in your case `push @copy_refs, \@copy` still uses the array and prevents it's destruction (memory is still occupied by the array).

Sorry, probably my explanation is not very intuitive and not very transparent. But the idea is that `@copy_refs` is keeping location for `@copy` array which prevents it's destruction.

Comment: I think you're answer is almost correct, but "inverted." You see the first set of output is from the code as presented. It's the second set of output that has the push removed. I think if you modify your answer as per Hakon Haegland's comment to my question, I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct -- I had it right in my mind, but poorly put in writing. Thank you, I made the correction of my answer.

Comment: While this answer deviates from the actual implementation a few demonstrable ways, it does convey the right idea, and the deviations only matter in corner cases one shouldn't care about.

Answer (score 1):

**It's an optimization** of Perl's virtual machine. (note that it could be due to "chance" as well, but in that case it's not)

*Disclaimer: I don't know the specifics of how Perl optimizes its memory management. However, I am knowledgeable about memory management an virtual machines in general.*

A few preliminary words, to be on the same page: Perl uses automatic [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) through a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) ([reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) to be precise). What this (aggressive?) sentence means is that in Perl, you don't need to manually request memory from the OS when you want to create an object, neither do you need to explicitly destroy your object to return memory to the OS.

When you do

```
my @copy = @array;
```

Perl allocates an array, and copies `@array` into it. Naively, allocating an array means asking the OS for some memory, and keeping track that this memory corresponds to the variable `@copy`. However, asking the OS for memory is very slow.

Furthermore, if every iteration of the `for` loop was allocating a new array at a new location, it would use a lot of memory: in your case, 10 times the size of `@array` (because you loop 10 times). This would be bad, especially since at the iteration *n+1*, you'd have no way to access the `@copy` allocated at iteration *n* (because you didn't keep a reference to it).

A visual representation might help understand. Take the following representation of the memory

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------
+                       empty
+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

After allocating `@copy` in the first iteration of the loop, you'll get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------
+  @copy |                     empty
+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, after the first iteration, there is no way to access `@copy` anymore. Perl can then destroy it, and your memory could then become:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------
+  empty |                   empty 
+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And then the second iteration would allocate `@copy` after the previous one:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------
+  empty |  @copy  |                empty
+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

At the third iteration, you'd get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------
+  empty |  empty  | @copy  |            empty
+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And so on for you ten iterations. It's obvious that having those `empty` spots does no good. This could be optimized in two ways:

- first, when freeing `@copy`, Perl could see that two `empty` blocks are next to each other, and merge them. This means that after freeing `@copy`, you'll go from

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
  +  @copy |                     empty
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
```

to

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
  +  empty |                     empty
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
```

to

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
  +                        empty
  +-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, when the next iteration allocates `@copy`, it will go at the same place the one from the previous iteration was. Thus, you'd get the same reference for all `@copy` from all iterations.

- Perl could simply see that within your loop, you allocate `@copy` but don't keep a reference to it, and therefore allocate only once some memory, which will be used for all iterations of `@copy`. In that case again, you'd get the same reference for all of your `@copy`.

I do not know if Perl uses either of this mechanism, however, it certainly uses something that produces a similar result (the result being "keeping memory low", which has for consequence "all the `@copy` from all the iterations have the same address). As per Ikegami's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211088/4990392), what really happens is something similar to my second bullet point.

---

Note that I've assumed in that answer that Perl doesn't request some new memory from the OS (= `malloc`) for each object it allocates, but rather requests for bulks of memory (using either `mmap` directly, or a large `malloc`). If Perl was using a single `malloc` for each object it allocates, then it becomes even more important to reuse memory from each `@copy`: calling `malloc` and `free` at each iteration would be very slow.

Comment: Re "*and therefore allocate only once some memory*", It does this. In fact, it takes this to the extreme. On scope exit, a lexical variable is either cleared (if nothing references it), or replaced with a freshly allocated var. Yes, you read that right, Perl *allocates* lexical vars on scope *exit*.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, very interesting! (would not have guessed, but it makes some sense) :)

Comment: That's why people were using `sub foo { my $var if 0; ... }` to create a variable that doesn't clear between calls to `foo`. Perl knows to clear/reallocate the variable on scope exit because `my` has the run-time effect of placing a directive on the stack to do so. By skipping the run-time effect of `my`, you get a never variable that never clears. (It's still lexically-scoped because of the compile-time effect of `my`.) That said, that's officially undefined behaviour, and one should use `sub foo { state $x; ... }` or `{ my $x; sub foo { ... } }` instead.

Comment: @ikegami Wow, that's nice! I've never seen `my $var if 0`, but I've seen people (mistakenly) do `my $var = x if y`, and always thought it was a bug of Perl to accept this form (because intuitively, you might think that it's equivalent to `my $var = $y && $x`, but it's not). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you intended something of this kind

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my @array = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

print "array ref is ".\@array."\n";

my @copy_refs;

for my $element(@array) {
    {                                       # new scope opens
        my @copy = @array;                  # new @copy array in new scope
        print "copy ref is ".\@copy."\n";
        push @copy_refs, \@copy;            # due new scope we have new array ref
    }                                       # and here scope closes 
                                            # @copy would be destroyed 
                                            # if it was not stored in @copy_ref
}

print Dumper(\@copy_refs) if $debug;
```

output ($debug = 0)

```
array ref is ARRAY(0x2664388)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x26ecb10)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x2663b00)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x2663d40)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x2663f80)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x26641c0)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x2664400)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x2664640)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x26e7250)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x27e5608)
copy ref is ARRAY(0x26889f0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't trying to achieve anything with this code. I was just curious about the behaviour.

Comment: Well, but sometimes it can be useful to understand what happens `under the hood/code` and it can be used for an advantage.